# Javadoc generation erroring on import statements

Tags: java, javadoc

I am trying to generate javadoc for a particular class. I am using this command

```
javadoc -d <javadoc folder directory> <file.java>
```

At the top of my file I have this line (just a standard Jackson import)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
```

When I try and generate Javadoc for this file, I get an error (along with many similar ones, all of them the same) that says this:

```
error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
```

Why does Javadoc care about this? How can I get around this error?